# How to get user credentials from firebase userdataMap

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have used firebase auth for login and registration. In that I created a map in relatime database to store users credential.

Like This

```
Future validateForm() async {
    FormState formSate = _formKey.currentState;
    if (formSate.validate()) {
      final User firebaseUser = (await firebaseAuth
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: _emailcontroller.text,
                  password: _passwordcontroller.text)
              .catchError((errMsg) {
        displayToast("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
      }))
          .user;

      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        Map userDataMap = {
          "name": _namecontroller.text.trim(),
          "email": _emailcontroller.text.trim(),
          "phone": _phonecontroller.text.trim(),
        };

        usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);

        displayToast("Succesfully Registered!", context);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return LocationHome();
        }));
      } else {
        displayToast("User was unable to create", context);
      }
    }
  }
}

displayToast(String msg, BuildContext context) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: msg);
}
```

Now please help me how to add extra information to this map from another page and also how to access these details from database to app

Comment: What's the problem you have on the other page, and accessing this data?

Comment: I dont know how to access it..Thats the problem

Comment: And when I tried to add extra info a new map is created in firebasde and olde one will get deleted

Comment: The FlutterFire documentation has a good section on reading from Firestore: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#read-data. If you get stuck implementing that for your use-case, edit your question to show what you tried in the new page to read the data.